# Executing R script within R 3.3.1 installed on windows

Tags: r

Sorry for a basic question. I'm trying run a R script called cuffdiff_gtf_attributes (please find it at [enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/malcook/851967bd087e1c3b6581) in R 3.3.1 installed on the Windows 7. The script is started with the below line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
```

When I type `cuffdiff_gtf_attributes` in R, it says `Error: object 'cuffdiff_gtf_attributes' not found`. Also, I tried `Rscript cuffdiff_gtf_attributes` that returned me: `Error: unexpected symbol in "Rscript cuffdiff_gtf_attributes".` 
Moreover, I tried `source('cuffdiff_gtf_attributes.R')`that seems to work and returned the usage of the script as bellow

```
Error: 
 usage: cuffdiff_gtf_attributes --input=<inputGTF> [--output=outputGTF] | --help
```

But, when I add the arguments as `source('cuffdiff_gtf_attributes.R') --input=file.gtf`, it says that: `Error: object 'file.gtf' not found`. I also tried this command as s`ource('cuffdiff_gtf_attributes.R') --input file.gtf`, it says that `Error: unexpected symbol in "source('cuffdiff_gtf_attributes.R') --input file.gtf"`

Sorry, I couldn't post a sample GTF file, you can find a short sample of it at [enter link description here](http://mblab.wustl.edu/GTF2.html)

Everything is the current path. Could you please help me out to execute the script?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't have `gtf` file to try on, but try this `cuffdiff_gtf_attributes -i ="in.gtf" -o = "out.gtf"`

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, which says: Error in cuffdiff_gtf_attributes - i = "file.gtf" : object 'cuffdiff_gtf_attributes' not found. I don't know why 'cuffdiff_gtf_attributes' not found. I added a link for finding a sample GTF file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a script file. You should run using Rscript instead for Rgui.exe. From a command prompt, navigate to the directory where file.gtf is and run:

```
"%Programfiles%\R\R-3.3.3\bin\Rscript" cuffdiff_gtf_attributes.R --input=file.gtf
```

Comment: I tried your suggested command, but it says: Error: '\R' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""%Programfiles%\R". I also did some modification on it, but it didn't work. Any suggestion, please!

Comment: @Mary You are running this on the R program, you should run this on the command prompt(cmd.exe)

Comment: Thank you very much, Marcelo. Now, it worked well and I accepted your answer.